# Can’t remove edges

Tags: uv, edges

[image]Hi, I don’t know the terminology, but does anyone know how to remove all the lines running around this bumper. I just want to to be one complete object. Clear seam, sharp, merge or join don’t work

Comment: It looks as if that's just the outline of a selected object viewed in Xray mode in which case you won't be able to remove them. Can you add an image of your complete screen (Window > Save Screenshot menu in Blender) so that we can see your settings.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Comment: Sorry, I was not connected to the Internet so I just used what I had at the time. These lines are affecting how the uv unwraps. It’s following them and breaking the object along these exact lines I’ll update tomorrow